# Importing CSS inline

Tags: iframe, inline, css-import

I have the following line in my code in an attempt to load styling into an iFrame:

```
<iframe style='color:blue;margin-left:30px;@import('../../custom/courses/css/stylesheets/course.css'); />
```

There are two problems:

1. Is it possible to import code using the **@import** as I am attempting to do above
2. The html code in my browser outputs the following: `<iframe style="color:blue;margin-left:30px;@import(" ..="" custom="" courses="" css="" stylesheets="" course.css');</iframe>`
   So, my css url path is very messed up.

**UPDATE**

My code:

```
(function($){
    var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
    cssLink.href = "../../custom/courses/css/stylesheets/course.css"; 
    cssLink.rel = "stylesheet"; 
    cssLink.type = "text/css"; 
    // frames['iframe'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
    jQuery('iframe.field-iframe-instance').css('border', '1px solid red');//.find('body').appendChild(cssLink);
})(jQuery);
```

The code on the iframe fails to take effect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS to iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that way. You can either include the style in the iframe target source or you attach it through javascript. Check this out: [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe/217833#217833)

Comment: You have a point but my code does not execute. Please see the code I added to my question